# Append new attribute in existing div jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a class in html like this below:

```
<div class="animsition">
```

Now I want to append a new attribute in that existing div using jquery. 
I like the animstion class will become:

```
 <div class="animsition" data-animsition-in-class="fade-in-left"
  data-animsition-in-duration="1000" data-animsition-out-class="fade-out-left"
  data-animsition-out-duration="800">
```

I tried but not work:
       `$(".animsition").attr("data-animsition-in-class","fade-in-left");`

How will I achieve this? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: getting error in console?by not working what do you mean?

Comment: There is no error in console.

Comment: Can you try console.log($(".animsition").length()) and see if it returns 1? If not, than JQuery can't find your div.

Answer (score 1):

Just take care you have added attribute within document.ready()

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".animsition").attr("data-animsition-in-class","fade-in-left");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put all those attributes in one object and use `for...in` loop and  `attr()`

```js
var attr = {
  'data-animsition-in-class': "fade-in-left",
  'data-animsition-in-duration': "1000",
  'data-animsition-out-class': "fade-out-left",
  'data-animsition-out-duration': "800"
}

for (var a in attr) {
  $('.animsition').attr(a, attr[a]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="animsition">Lorem</div>
```

Or you can use `Object.keys()`

```js
var attr = {
  'data-animsition-in-class': "fade-in-left",
  'data-animsition-in-duration': "1000",
  'data-animsition-out-class': "fade-out-left",
  'data-animsition-out-duration': "800"
}

Object.keys(attr).forEach(function(a) {
  $('.animsition').attr(a, attr[a]);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="animsition">Lorem</div>
```